# How to programmatically create an animation that linearly interpolate between two rotations?

Tags: unity, animation, rotation, quaternion

I would like to programmatically create an animation that linearly interpolate between two angles (using the shortest path).
I wrote the following code :

```
Animation anim = gameObject.GetComponent<Animation>();

Quaternion a = Quaternion.Euler( 35.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
Quaternion b = Quaternion.Euler(330.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

AnimationClip clip = new AnimationClip();
clip.SetCurve("", typeof(Transform), "localRotation.x", AnimationCurve.Linear(0.0f, a.x, 1.0f, b.x));
clip.SetCurve("", typeof(Transform), "localRotation.y", AnimationCurve.Linear(0.0f, a.y, 1.0f, b.y));
clip.SetCurve("", typeof(Transform), "localRotation.z", AnimationCurve.Linear(0.0f, a.z, 1.0f, b.z));
clip.SetCurve("", typeof(Transform), "localRotation.w", AnimationCurve.Linear(0.0f, a.w, 1.0f, b.w));

clip.legacy = true;
anim.AddClip(clip, "test");
```

What happen is this : the angle goes `35 => 100 => 200 => 330`

Instead, I would like it to go`35 => 0 => -30`

Also (another issue) the interpolation seems not linear (left : what I got, right: after setting the curve linear using the editor) :

[image]

As an example, the following code does what I want, it is linear and take shortest path (but without using curves) :

```
Quaternion a = Quaternion.Euler( 35.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
Quaternion b = Quaternion.Euler(331.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(a, b, Time.time % 1.0f);
```

Comment: Can you clarify why you want to programmatically generate an animation using curves, rather than using the lerping code you've shown? Getting a linear blend between arbitrary rotations is going to be challenging in terms of Euler angle curves.

Comment: I want to import and animate some 3D models from a non standard format that contains bones and other animation info (this is from a old DOS game). At first i was doing everything by hand, including bone transformation, but I feel like it was like reinventing the wheel and decided to use unity animation feature instead.